# plane wave move out

Tags: physics, matlab, mathematical-physics

[image]

I have a plane wave that is recorded by a set of receivers with x spacing between them (see the sketch). in the sketch (plane wave in black slant line, receivers are the little circles in black and the line in blue is the surface). The place wave arrives with an angle to the normal (alpha) at the receivers. The wave was generated from 2000 cells to the left of my receivers line and 5000 cell deep below my line. Given I have the recording time of the arrival at each receiver (black circle) I was trying to correct for it and shift it into a normal incident rather than slanted as of the plane wave originated from deep below the receivers (5000 below). I do have the velocity of the medium below, arrival time, and angel of incident and I want to accomplish that. My final gaol is not to linear move out the arrive but rather shift it is if it was originated below the receivers.

one approach I am thinking of is by multiplying the recording time at the first station by the cosine of the angel and then subtracting that from the first recording time 
 (t1)-(cos(alpha)*(t1)).

Comment: If you know the direction of propagation and speed of the wave, you can find the difference in arrival times and shift two the receivers' signal so that it matches the third. An easy way would be FFT --> Phase Ramp --> IFFT. A more accurate result could probably be found with time-domain resampling, but I suspect the former would be easier and give good enough results.

Comment: It seems your question is more physical than math. You can ask your question on [here](http://physics.stackexchange.com) too.

Comment: Thank you very much. I am still not quite sure how to do this but I will give the physics website a try and see what that brings me. Your comments are much appreciated.